# Which class is responsible to implement Bootstrap class loader?

Tags: java

I am beginner in field of classloaders in java.I read that Extension ClassLoader  & Application class loader in JVM is implemented by  sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader & sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader respectively. Which class is responsible to implement Bootstrap class loader?

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap class loader loads the core Java libraries[5] located in the /jre/lib directory. This class loader, which is part of the core JVM, is written in native code.  I.e. there is no class...

Comment: The bootstrap classloader will vary across implementations of the jvm and it is written in native code.  It is not a class written in java code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I know very well what it does. If its not a class,than what it is? please explain little more

Comment: Fundamentally Java is a platform independent language and running java requires a jvm.  This jvm code in contrast needs to be platform specific and is therefore written in a native language, for example Sun's jvm is written in C.

Comment: Thanks,agree.I know about native codes,even many methods in Object class are written in native language. My thing is where the native codes corresponding to boot strap class loader is written.Is this written in some file which is executed to load JDK class files from rt.jar ?

Comment: Yeah in the jre/bin folder somewhere I think, I don't know what file.